# What does "scanf("%d",&a[i])" mean?

Tags: c

First time seeing this, what does this mean? Specifically the `&a[i]` part.

```
scanf("%d",&a[i])
```

Comment: This is kindergarten-level ABC's of the language. What does you favorite C book say about this? (And why do you insist on mixing HTML elements with C code?)

Comment: Do you really have HTML entities like `&amp;` in your C code? Why?

Comment: No, my question was edited. I knew about that, but I'm sure about &amp;a[i] part

Comment: @Barmar this might be the new &amp;ed up C.

Comment: @St531: `&amp;a[i]` does not make any sense at all. It actually supposed to be `&a[i]` not `&amp;a[i]`. The `&amp;a[i]` is just HTML markup. `&amp;` is HTML way of encoding `&` glyph in web pages.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like C code that has been converted to HTML entities, so that it can be displayed on a web page. `&amp;` is how you enter an `&` character in HTML. If you look at it in a web browser you'll see the intended C code, which is

```
scanf("%d",&a[i])
```

`&a[i]` means the address of the `i`th element of the array `a`. So this reads an integer from standard input, and stores it in `a[i]`.

Don't try to read C from the HTML source code.